# System.InvalidCastException

Tags: c#

System.InvalidCastException: "Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.ConsoleKeyInfo" к типу "System.IConvertible"."

Не до конца понимаю как сделать грамотно ввод с клавиатуры, чтобы выбирало из трех. Буду благодарен за помощь

```
switch (Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadKey()))
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(Three[0]);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    }

                case 2:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(Three[1]);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(Three[2]);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    }

                default:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Выбор только из трех");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        break;
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar - '0';

if (i < 1 || i > 3)
  Console.WriteLine("Выбор только из трёх");
else
  Console.WriteLine(Three[i-1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Считывайте из потока стандартного ввода строку, парсите из неё число, а потом делайте `switch` по этому числу

```
switch (int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()))
{
    ...
}
```

Метод, который вы вызываете сейчас, возвращает вам не число, а структуру `ConsoleKeyInfo`, описывающую клавишу клавиатуры, которая не может быть приведена к типу `long`.

`switch` тут, кстати, тоже не нужен:

```
Console.WriteLine(Three[int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) - 1]);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Разумеется, работать будет только при адекватном вводе (можете в условии его проверить, прежде чем в индексатор его передавать).